# "She was supposed to phone ...", What is the active voice?

Tags: subjunctives, active-voice

Is the following sentence in the passive voice?

> She **was supposed** to phone Jack last night.

If yes, What is the active voice version of it?

Comment: @Araucaria But if I'm not mistaken, the top answer in that question suggests that *(I'm) supposed to (do something)* is not in the passive voice. In that case, the answer to this question would be "No, it's not", and its active voice would be irrelevant.

Comment: @DamkerngT., MAR , You are right, I am wrong! I should read more carefully! (although, FWIW, I don't like that main answer. Reason being that there are many passive clauses that have no active versions. For example, "MAR is reputed to be a genius at chemistry". )

Comment: @Araucaria "Supposed" is a participial adjective (a lexical modal - epistemic?), so the matrix clause is an adjectival passive.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, indeed. Are adjectival passives really passives though? (I know H&P present them as such, but ...) I don't understand why H&P decide that *meant* and *supposed* are adjectives when they fail every adjective test and pass every verb one ... :(

Comment: @Araucaria H&P say (p1440) "supposed" has a "specialised sense" and claim that although it is morphologically related to a past participle of a verb, its meaning has changed so it is no longer comparable to a verbal passive with same form. They go on to say that its connection with a passive proper is purely historic. They cover the point about whether adjectival passives  are really passives on p 1436 where they say they are passive only in a derivative sense, and that they are a complex-intransitive construction.

Comment: The Cambridge dictionary has got it right, see [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/supposed).

Comment: @Shannak Can you see now that "supposed" is not a verb but an adjective, so it is not a passive sentence, but an active one? But if "supposed" is replaced by a verb participle like "persuaded", and there was a _by-_ phrase, it would be passive: _She was persuaded by her friends to phone Jack last night_. The active version would then be _Her friends persuaded her to phone Jack last night_.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the following sentence in the passive voice?

No.

The passive voice has a syntax rule that is followed - *{to be} + {past participle}* - but another thing that passive voice does is flip or switch a subject and target.  Without this "flip" or "switch" you aren't really expressing anything "passively."

> I walked the dog.
>
> The dog was walked by me.  ("I walked the dog" is still what is happening, this is just an alternate way to express it.)

You can't do this with your example, because what would be the "passive subject" - *she* - is not a target of any action.  It's the actual subject of the action.

Another heuristic: In a passive voice expression, you can always add *by X* to indicate the subject.  You can't do that with your example either.

Comment: The reason it's not a passive sentence is that "supposed" is not a verb but an adjective, so it must be an active sentence. But if "supposed" is replaced by a verb past participle like "persuaded", and there was a _by-_ phrase, it would be passive: _She was persuaded by her friends to phone Jack last night_. The active version would then be _Her friends persuaded her to phone Jack last night_.